# How to edit .pub format files on fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, gimp, fedora-14

Is there an aplication/software that I can use to edit the Microsoft publisher (.pub) format files on fedora14.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no."

The longer answer is that you can probably set up Publisher with [CodeWeaver's](http://www.codeweavers.com) Crossover Linux with [some degree of success](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/search/?name=publisher).

Probably using that and slowly/rapidly transitioning existing files to [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) or [LibreOffice's](http://www.libreoffice.org) Draw would be the best way to go.